# mercurial ssl access allow pull BUT require authentication for push

Tags: mercurial, apache2, hgweb

I have set up a mercurial server through SSL. In the apache config file I have set up an authentication using a mysql database.

I would like everyone to be able to pull from the repository without credentials, but restrict the push right to authenticated users. The way it is done now either everyone is authenticated both for pull and push, or nobody is.

My apache configuration is this:

```
<Location /hg/repo>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Repository Access"
   AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
   AuthUserFile /dev/null
   AuthMySQL                    On
   AuthMySQL_Authoritative      On
   AuthMySQL_Host               localhost
   AuthMySQL_DB                 repo
   AuthMySQL_User               repo
   AuthMySQL_Password_Table     users_auth_external
   AuthMySQL_Group_Table        users_auth_external
   AuthMySQL_Username_Field     username
   AuthMySQL_Password_Field     passwd
   AuthMySQL_Group_Field        groups
   AuthMySQL_Encryption_Types   SHA1Sum
   Require group                pink-image
   <LimitExcept GET>
       Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

hg also requires authentication for the ssl pull, Regardless on the LimitExcept switch.

Is there a way to limit the authentication only for pushing to the repository?

A simple http access would not be sufficient because if somebody is a developer she checks out the code through https.

SSH access is not possible because some of the developers have the ssh port forbidden by the firewall.

One of the solutions would be if hg would remember the https credentials.

Thank You for reading the question.

Answer (score 3):

The authentication should be wrapped into the exception rule.

```
<Location /hg/repo>
   <LimitExcept GET>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Repository Access"
        AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
        AuthUserFile /dev/null
        AuthMySQL                    On
        AuthMySQL_Authoritative      On
        AuthMySQL_Host               localhost
        AuthMySQL_DB                 repo
        AuthMySQL_User               repo
        AuthMySQL_Password_Table     users_auth_external
        AuthMySQL_Group_Table        users_auth_external
        AuthMySQL_Username_Field     username
        AuthMySQL_Password_Field     passwd
        AuthMySQL_Group_Field        groups
        AuthMySQL_Encryption_Types   SHA1Sum
        Require group                pink-image      
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. As an additional note, only the `Require` option (`Require group`, `Require valid-user`, etc) needs to be encapsulated within the LimitExcept clause. This allows further granularity in regards to access control (i.e. certain users/groups get read, others get read/write)

Answer (score 2):

```
One of the solutions would be if hg would remember the https credentials.
```

It can remember the credentials for push and pull.  Look under the `auth` section of `hg help config` if you don't mind adding the details to one of the config files (either user's config or the repository clone's `hgrc`)

This would mean putting the password in the config file which you might not like so you could use the [Mercurial Keyring Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeyringExtension) instead which stores the password more securely.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out automatic credentials are not enough. The repository aught to be accessible through the web interface. However the same config file pops up an authentication dialog in the browser which makes the web interface unusable.